# what is session_reset() exactly?

Tags: php, session, undefined, session-cookies, undefined-index

I want to know what is session_reset() for and when should we use it ?
when I use it I get an error like this: "Call to undefined index session_reset()". 
I hope you know something about it .
Thank you in advance.

Comment: session_start — Start new or resume existing session

Comment: session_reset() or session_start() or both?

Comment: `Call to undefined index session_start()` - session_start is a function not an index within an array.

Comment: I'm really sorry . I mean session_reset() . I changed my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

session_reset — Re-initialize session array with original values.

Example

first create a session variable

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["A"] = "Some Value";
   echo $_SESSION["A"];

//Output: Some Value

//if you need to rollback the session values after seting new value to session variables use session_reset()

   $_SESSION["A"] = "Some New Value";  // set new value

  session_reset();  // old session value restored
   echo $_SESSION["A"];

//Output: Some Value
?>
```